# Expressionengine - Freemember Email - invalid link sent

Tags: freemember, forgot-password

We want the email sent with the reset link, but the link being sent is giving an error: "The form you submitted contained the following errors
The password reset token does not appear to be valid. Please check the link you followed."

Link sent: http://XXXXX?ACT=17&id={resetcode}

EE2.10.1
Email sent using Freemember

There is a row in the "exp_reset_password" table that has the resetcode exactly matching the one in the email.

Thanks for your help in advance.

FORM CODE:

```
{exp:freemember:forgot_password form:id="forgotPasswordForm" return="profile/forgot_sent"}
    <div class="step" id="step1" data-step="1">
        <div class="pg-lo-header">LOGIN</div>
            <div class="pg-lo-body">
            <strong>Forgot password?</strong><br/><br/>
            <div class="pg-sing-lable">Tell us your email address and we will send you a temporary password.  You can choose a new password when you login.</div>
            <div class="field-wrapper row">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="required" value="{email}"><br />
                {if "{error:email}" != ""}<div class="errorMsg">{email} does not exist.</div>{/if}
            </div>
            <div class="po-popup-btns">
              <a class="btn btn-reset-password" id="close" href="javascript:void(0);">SEND EMAIL</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step hide" id="step2" data-step="2">
        <div class="pg-lo-header">LOGIN</div>
            <div class="pg-lo-body">
            <strong>Forgot password?</strong><br/><br/>
            <div class="pg-sing-lable">Email Sent.</div>

           <div class="po-popup-btns">
              <a class="btn btn-close" id="close" href="javascript:void(0);">OK</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{/exp:freemember:forgot_password}
```

Submit listener:

```
$(".btn-reset-password").live("click",function(e){
        var _form = $(this).closest("form");
        e.preventDefault();
        if (validateForm(_form)) {
            $.ajax({
                url: _form.attr("action"),
                data: _form.serialize(),
                dataType: 'html',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(resp){
                    console.log(resp);
                    if ($(resp).find("input").length == 0) {
                        //console.log($(resp).find("input"));
                        gotoStep(2);
                    } else {
                        $(".po-popup").html(resp);
                    }
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log("error submitting");
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log("error");
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. It looks as though EE's native password reset doesn't understand Freemember's reset code.

I was able to fix this issue by creating a template with Freemember's [reset password](https://github.com/devdemon/freemember/blob/master/docs/reset_password_tag.md) tag and passed the folder and file name to Freemember's forgot_password tag as a [reset parameter](https://github.com/devdemon/freemember/blob/master/docs/forgot_password_tag.md#reset).